# Magento 2.1.2 install error on PHP 5.4.38

Tags: php, magento

I have downloaded Magento CE 2.1.2 with test data and uploaded the zip file to my server and unzipped it. My server is Centos 5.1.1 and my PHP is 5.4.38 (cli)...

I followed the instructions on the Magento setup to set file permissions here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install-quick-ref.html#mage-owner-about-group

When I go to www.myurl.com/magento/setup I get this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/www/vhosts/timpiele.com/httpdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php on line 411

When I run stat -c '%a' magento I get 755...

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2.1.2 requires at least **PHP 5.6.5**: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.2/composer.json#L11

Comment: That's not what it says here: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/system-requirements.html